# model_to_dict() with a @property field is not being included

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to include a field that is a `property` in the model_to_dict `fields` list.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='bla...')

    ...snipped...

    @property
    def thumbnail_url(self):
        return self.thumbnail.url

    def toJSON(self):
        return model_to_dict(self, fields=[..., 'thumbnail_url',...])
```

When I call Person.toJSON() it does **not** include `thumbnail_url` field.

What is wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: A property is not a field, hence it will not be included.

Comment: hmmm. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57303346/11576212 this person said it solved his problem. Provided properties don't work what is the workaround to get the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my current fix. I am open to another approach that works cleaner with `model_to_dict()`

```
@property
def thumbnail_url(self):
    return self.thumbnail.url

def toJSON(self):
    return {
        **model_to_dict(self, fields=['all', 'my', 'fields']),
        **{'thumbnail_url': self.thumbnail_url }
          }
```

Answer (score 2):

You would want a serializer instead, it might be cleaner instead of model_to_dict()

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/

This is what the serializer class would look like:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from .people import Person # replace with where your Person model is at.


class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = [
            'all',
            'your',
            'fields',
            'thumbnail_url'
        ]
```

And instead of `model_to_dict(self, fields=['all', 'my', 'fields']),`:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from people.models import Person
from people.serializers import PersonSerializer

... 

instance = Person.objects.all().first()  # Getting first person for the example
if instance:
    data = PersonSerializer(instance).data
return Response(data)
```